# Implementing the loss function using mse

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, naivebayes

I'm using MSE to measure the loss. In the below code, I implemented loss_mse function that should computes MSE for the input set with the given theta

```
def loss_mse(X,y,theta):
    length = len(y)
    predictions = X.dot(theta)
    error = (1/2*length) * np.sum(np.square(predictions - y))
    return error
```

To test the above function, I wrote the following test cases:

```
X = np.array([[2.0, 1.0, 3.0], [3.0, 6.0, 2.0]])
y =  np.array([1.0, 1.0])
theta = np.array([[1.0], [2.0],[1.0]])
error = loss_mse(X, y, theta)
print(error)
```

I have to get the answer as `73` but I'm getting `584`. I don't understand where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are multiplying by `length` rather than dividing.

Try

```
1/(2*length) * np.sum(np.square(predictions - y))
```

For the given input, this results in `146`, did you perhaps mean for it to be `1/(4*length)`?

Comment: I just used the formula given in my textbook and got 146 but based on the provided test cases I need to get 73. I don't understand why do we need to mean for it?

Comment: The generic MSE formula would be `(1/length) * np.sum(np.square(predictions - y))`, so I'm not sure what exactly they are looking for in your case